# Cross Browser compatible CustomEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, cross-browser, jquery-events

I need to create a Custom Event which will pass some data to the event listener. I already created one like below

**CustomEvent**

```
var event = new CustomEvent('store', { 'detail': obj });
document.getElementById("Widget").dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Listener**

```
document.getElementById("Widget").addEventListener('store', function (e) {
  console.log(e.detail);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e.detail.name+"<br>"+e.detail.address;
}, false);
```

It is working fine in browsers such as Chrome and Firefox but not working in IE11. I am getting an error in IE:

> Object doesn't support this action
>
> CustomEvent is not working in IE.

How can I make this cross-browser compatible ? I don't want to use jQuery `trigger()` because the `Listener` might not be in a page having jQuery

Comment: IE11 dont support optinal paramin listner. in your case 'false' try without false

Comment: @Sandeeproop I tried with that but the execution stops at var event = new CustomEvent('store', { 'detail': obj }); in IE11

Comment: I think CustomEvent constructor is not supported in IE11. check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Browser_compatibility. plollyfill is also avalible check that out

Answer (score 26):

CoustomEvent constructor is not supported in IE11.
you can use following pollyfill

```
(function () {

     if ( typeof window.CustomEvent === "function" ) return false;

     function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
         params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
         var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
         evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
         return evt;
     }

     CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

     window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
})();
```

Copied from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the "Can I use" page and what it says about the Custom Events.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=customevent

Specifically, read this quote:

> While a window.CustomEvent object exists, it cannot be called as a
>   constructor. Instead of new CustomEvent(...), you must use e =
>   document.createEvent('CustomEvent') and then e.initCustomEvent(...)

Comment: How can I send the data { 'detail': obj } using this method ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you save the data in the event objects itself can work. For instance, something like this. `e.myData = { detail: obj};`