# In Vue - how can I trigger a broadcast to pick up event in a different control?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a component for steps, and I need to trigger an event in my steps component when I click on the next button.

This event should be picked up by a different component, that is representing the content of the page in the current step.

This is what I have tried:

#### Steps component template:

```
<template>
  <div class="steps">
    <div class="steps-content">
      <section class="steps-panel" v-for="(stepPage, index) in steps">
        <header class="posA wrap pTs">{{$t(title)}}</header>
        <component :is="stepPage">
           <!-- Summary component is injected here -->
        </component>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div role="navigation">
      <ol class="fixed nav nav--block steps-nav w100">
        <li class="steps-label txtCap" v-for="(stepPage, index) in steps">
          {{$t(stepPage.name)}}
        </li>
      </ol>
      <button class="steps-button" type="button">
        <i class="pf pf-arrow-left"></i>
        <span class="steps-button-label">{{$tc('previous')}}</span>
      </button>
      <button class="steps-button" type="button" v-on:click="next">
        <span class="steps-button-label">{{$tc('next')}}</span>
        <i class="pf pf-arrow-right"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### Steps component method:

```
methods: {
  next(event) {
    console.log('emit stepnext')
    this.$emit('stepnext')
  }
}
```

I call this with `v-on:click="next"` in the steps template (on the 'next' button)
From the console.log, I see that the click event is executed, and the $emit call does not trigger any error, so it seems to work fine at this point.

### Summary component

The summary component is one of the components in `steps', and is loaded by this entry in the Steps template:

```
<component :is="stepPage"></component>
```

In the Summary component that knows what to do when this is clicked, I try to pick up on this event by having this in the template:

```
<div class="wrap" v-on:stepnext="stepfinish">
 ... content ...
</div>
```

... and a method in the summary component named `stepfinish` that does the action, but it seems like the emitted event never reaches my summary component.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you demonstrate the problem in a fiddle or codepen?

Comment: I added some more details about the structure. This should be enough to understand the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `event bus`
Here is some snippet from the official docs:

```
var bus = new Vue()

// in component A's method
bus.$emit('id-selected', 1)

// in component B's created hook
bus.$on('id-selected', function (id) {
  // ...
})
```

link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Here is a blog on the same: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Yes, I also was thinking about this, but it was a bit hard to figure out from the vue guide how to make this globally available in any component. The other link you shared explained this perfectly. Thank you! :)

Comment: alligator link is very useful to understand

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution when using `$root`:

```
// trigger
this.$root.$emit('my-event');

// listen
this.$root.$on('my-event');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you totally want to decouple your components, or you want to communicate across Vue "apps" and/or different frameworks (React, ...), then you can also use the DOM Native events:

```js
      document.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent("myapp:someClick", {
          detail: {
            id: 1,
            someMoreCustomPayload: "bar",
          },
        })
      )
```

And on the receiver's side:

```js
    document.addEventListener("myapp:someClick", (ev) => {
      const { id, someMoreCustomPayload } = ev.detail
      ...
    })
```

IE11 can also handle CustomEvents but apparently has no support for `detail`, but can be [polyfilled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37566606/220292).